# Infinity in double primitive

Tags: java

I found that this code work well and when I print it I have "Infinity". I don't understand how can we put value Infinity in primitive type, I thought that it will be error.

```
  String s = "Infinity";
    double d  = Double.valueOf(s);
    System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: with `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`?

Comment: What do you mean by infinity? Really, you ought not to model it at all.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_non-numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_non-numbers)

Comment: The fact that the data type is called "primitive" has nothing to do with it.  A `double` has 64 bits.  That means, there are 2^64 distinct `double` values.  One of those values is called _positive infinity_, and another one is called _negative infinity_.